# Не синхронизируется Gradle в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

В школе стоит программа-фильтр. В связи с этим после установки Android Studio (установилась вроде бы нормально) и создании первого проекта, не синхронизируется Gradle. Пишет, что соединение с хостом сброшено и соответственно не получается скомпилировать проект. Что можно сделать в этом случае?

Comment: Фильтр стоит на ученическом компе?

Comment: Если там прокси сервер, через который идёт весь трафик, то нужно указать настройки прокси-сервера либо в settings.gradle в корне проекта, либо глобально - где-то в конфигах самого гредла. Загуглить будет не сложно.

Comment: @gbg Фильтр на всех компах

Comment: подойти к учителю информатики и объяснить проблему

Comment: если никак с интернетом не получится, то можно дома проект скачать, gradle прочекает все зависимости, а потом каталог .gradle перенести на школьный пк